# Which websites allow you to buy-in with a very small stack?

Tags: texas-hold-em, online, cash-game

Recently, I’ve been reading about a small stack strategy for cash games. It involves entering the table with only 20 big blinds. Unfortunately, it seems that many poker websites (e.g. 888poker and PokerStars) don’t allow you to buy-in with such a small stack. Are there any websites that do allow this?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because any answers to this question would have a very short shelf life and be no use to future users. It also does not take an expert at poker to answer this question, just a little research on your part.

Comment: @Jon: It's quite difficult to find out this information. Moreover, some people here might have experience playing as short stacks on different sites, and can suggest which ones are the best. However, you are free to vote as you wish.

Comment: Joe you won't find really short buy ins. It is not a thing. It does not attract players that give much action and a lot of player will simply not play were the buy ins are to low. There are not many online card rooms anymore. So look around.